# Showing confirmation before changing the value of a checkbox in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a confirmation dialog within my application. Currently i'm a bit confused what to do with the logic.

**UserDetailsComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange  } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal/modal.component';

import { ApiService } from '../../assets/services/api.service';

import { UserDetails } from '../../assets/classes/controller-details';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.scss']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {

    @Input('cmd') cmd_s: boolean;
    changeLog: string[] = []

    userDetailForm: FormGroup; 

    id: any;
    data: UserDetails = new UserDetails();

    submitted = false;
    active = false;

    private sub: any;

    constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private apiService: ApiService,
      private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
        this.id = params['id']; //console.log(this.id);
        this.getData(this.id);
      })
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    confirmDialog(e){
      if(e.target.checked){
        console.log('changing to on');
        this.active = true;
      }else{
        console.log('chenging to off');
        this.active = true;
      }
      this.active = false;
    }

    toOn(){
      this.controllerDetailForm.controls['status'].setValue(1);
      console.log('Changed to on');
    }

    toOff(){
      this.controllerDetailForm.controls['status'].setValue(0);
      console.log('Changed to off');
    }

    createForm(){
      this.controllerDetailForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [this.data.id],
        name: [this.data.name, Validators.required],
        status: [this.data.status, ]
      });
    }
}
```

I've create three functions `confirmationDialog()`, `toOn()`, `toOff()` to manipulate the value before and after change. I thought that it could help but me to get this done, however now i realized that there's something not right.

Below is my modal.

**Modal**

```
<input type="checkbox" #status formControlName="status" class="switch-input" [checked]="data.status" (change)="confirmDialog($event)">

<div bsModal #smallModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>   
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="smallModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you wan't to change?</p>    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Yes" (click)="onConfirmation() ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="smallModal.hide()">No</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Example,
If the current status is On, then the confirmation dialog should has:

- 'Yes' button to change it to off
- While 'No' button revert/prevent the changes

What would be the best practice to give a confirmation dialog from changing a radio button?

Any kind of help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for your situation, `change` event is late because the status and `ngModel` of the `checkbox` has changed already, you can use `(click)` to achieve the confirm part.

And for prevent part, you can use `$event.preventDefault()` to avoid the checkbox's status to be changed from `(click)` event.

I have make a simple plunker [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/VbORG3NN2q9VlLyQDda3?p=preview) which used the `window.confirm` to show the confirm dialog.

Comment: that is so cool man, im sorry for the late reply. anyway im gonna try it now! thanks for the help!

Comment: this doesn't work with promises. do you have a work around for that?

Comment: @user781861 If you want some help, please be specified first. :)

Comment: i use primeng confirmation service to popup a question. the e.preventDefault() wasn't working after the user had selected yes/no (use promises). so they event got detached or something. i was able to get it to work though by putting e.preventDefault() at the beginning of the click event and then using [(ngModel)] to set the checkbox status afterward.