# Angular 2 verify data before allowing checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox on it for admins to edit users. The user object has a boolean object `isAdmin`. I want prevent users from modifying their own account, but still allow them to see the values, but no matter what I do, the I can't prevent the checkbox from checking. The data does not submit (correctly), so refreshing the page works, but I am trying to take advantage of two-way binding.

my component method:

```
updateUser(event, key, user) {
  if (user.$key !== this.currentUserId) {
    console.log('updating');
    this.loginService.updateUser(user.$key, key, event.checked);
  } else {
    // somehow don't allow the checking of the box?
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<md-card class="responsive-card">
    <md-card *ngFor="let user of (users$ | async)">
        <md-card-content>
          <!-- checkbox here -->
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</md-card>
```

Attempt 1:

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="user.isAdmin" name="isAdmin" (change)="updateUser($event, 'isAdmin', user)" #isAdmin>
        Admin
</md-checkbox>
```

Attempt 2 (I thought, maybe just one way binding?):

```
<md-checkbox [ngModel]="user.isAdmin" name="isAdmin" (change)="updateUser($event, 'isAdmin', user)">
        Admin
</md-checkbox>
```

Attempt 3 (bind to the checked attribute?):

```
<md-checkbox [attr.checked]="user.isAdmin" name="isAdmin" (change)="updateUser($event, 'isAdmin', user)">
        Admin
</md-checkbox>
```

Visual gif of the issue (Top user should not allow me to modify it):

[image: gif of issue]

Comment: I added `[disabled]="isCurrentUser(user.$key)"` to the inputs... that is probably the best way to do it, but I suppose I would like to know how to check something before allowing a checkbox to check itself.

Comment: see whether this post help or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851705/showing-confirmation-before-changing-the-value-of-a-checkbox-in-angular2/43852051#43852051

Comment: That is another option, however clicks to seem to occur on disabled elements as well.

Comment: no, click event doesn't occur when checkbox is disabled.

Comment: Click seemed to trigger even on disabled. My new thought is to use a promise and a view child somehow

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `checked` property binding instead of `attr.checked`. Also your `isAdmin` should be free from quotes

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="user.isAdmin" name="isAdmin" (change)="updateUser($event, isAdmin, user)">
        Admin
</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Firstly, no it shouldn't. Maybe not the best way of doing it, but since I am reusing this method for a `verified` element, I need to distinguish between the two. The method works fine, but the checking does not reflect the model. Secondly, this solution did not work.

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce the same?

Comment: I will try... I am terrible at using plunker.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use [checked] = "user.isAdmin" instead of [attr.checked], that is,

```
<md-checkbox [checked] = "user.isAdmin" name = "isAdmin" (change) = "updateUser($event, 'isAdmin', user)">
   Admin
</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Your answer adds nothing to Aravind's and also does not work.